# Applying custom function to a column of lists in pandas, how to handle exceptions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of 15000 record which has text column (column name = clean) as a list, please refer below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d9hS.png)

I need to find the minimum value in each row and add as a new column called min

```
def find_min(x):
    x = min(x)
    return(x)
```

I tried to pass the above function

```
df1['min'] = df1['clean'].map(find_min)
```

Getting below error

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

It seems there is an empty list, how to address this as I am having 15000 records
Please advise

Comment: your function is named `min`, so you no longer have access to the builtin min function in the current scope. Try renaming your outer function. Btw you could just do `df1['clean'].map(min)` without having to define a min function.

Comment: 1: there's a built-in function called `min` already. 2: you're overwriting it. 3: you're calling `min(x)` from within the function itself, resulting in an infinite recursion.

Comment: @cs95. I tried. Getting this error "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence". Type of my column in pd.series.

Comment: That kinda makes sense, if the list is empty, min([]) makes no sense. Btw that's a different question from the one currently being asked, so maybe update your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have a list of columns, let us try handling errors in your function using try/except (EAFP pattern):

```
def find_min(x):
    try: 
        return min(x)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

df1['min'] = df1['clean'].map(find_min)
```

---

Another way is to skip the function and define this inline:

```
df1['min'] = df1['clean'].map(lambda x: min(x) if len(x) else np.nan)
```

---

You can also do this using a list comprehension, which is quite fast:

```
df1['min'] = [find_min(x) for x in df1['clean']]
```

or,

```
df1['min'] = [min(x) if len(x) else np.nan for x in df1['clean']]
```